# Find Row in Table

Tags: jquery

I have the following setup

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkeTD/2/

On the click of the button, I want to read the row number entered in the textbox and highlight that row. Eg if user enters 4, highlight 4th row. If row number is invalid, alert user to enter valid number.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var num = $("#inp").val();
});
```

How do I find the row and highlight it?

Comment: You already selected an answer, but check out the alternative I provided in case you want a "text search" option also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:eq(...)` selector:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var num = $("#inp").val();
    $("tr").css("background", "transparent");
    $("tr:eq(" + num + ")").css("background", "red");
});
```

`tr:eq(0)` will select the header row.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkeTD/7/)

Comment: nice..how do I reset the table when the button is clicked again to search for another row?

Comment: See the edit. Just change background to all rows before changing the selected row background.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Can you also look at questions/21499096/counting-rows-for-grouping-and-paging

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
     var num = parseInt($("#inp").val());
     if (num) {
         var row = $("#movie tr:nth-of-type(" + num + ") td");
         if (row.length == 0) {
             alert("Invalid row number");
         } else {
             row.css("background", "yellow");
         }
     } else {
         alert("Invalid row number");
     }
 });
```

Note that you should validate user entry (here with parseInt()) to avoid code injection or any kind of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This fits a situation slightly different than yours, but it is an alternative approach. It has a nice feature ( intentional bug? ) where it also works for names, release years, etc...

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/Q7HYE/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#btn").on( "click", function(){
        $("td").removeClass("highlight")
        var num = $("#inp").val();
        console.log( "search: " + num )
        if ( $("td:contains(" + num + ")").length > 0 )
            $("td:contains(" + num + ")").closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
        else
            alert("Not found.")
    });
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlight {
    background: #f00;
    color: #fff
}
```

**Screenshot...**

[image: Working example.]